# MySQL stored procedure insert select

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`generic_user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `copy_GenericOperation`(IN genericInputID INT)

BEGIN

   DECLARE newOperationInfoId int;

   Insert into genericOperationInfoTable(createdBy, creationDate, modifiedBy, modificationDate, genericOperationId, cycleTime, notes, overrideFlag, processId, subProcessId, setupId)

   select createdBy, createdDate, updatedBy, updatedDate, operationId, cycleTime, notes, override, processId, subProcessId, setupId 

   from operationinfo

   where id=genericInputID;

   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as newOperationInfoId;

   SET newOperationInfoId=LAST_INSERT_ID();

   Insert into genericTransactionTable(id, parameterId, value, genericOperationInfoId, overrideFlag)

   SELECT

      ot.parameterId, ot.value, newOperationInfoId, ot.overrideFlag

   FROM genericTransactionTable as ot

   where ot.genericOperationInfoId=genericInputID;

END
```

I'm trying to create a stored procedure such that the last generated ID from the inserted table should get inserted into the next table

First insert is working fine but I'm not sure why any data is not getting inserted in 2nd table

Comment: likely where ot.genericOperationInfoId=genericInputID; is never true..and why inserting to the same table?

Comment: issue might be related to the way you are setting the value of newOperationInfoId.

Comment: Does `genericTransactionTable` have a column whose name is the same name as `genericInputID`? It will reference the table's column, not your variable. I assume you have changed the column and variable names in your question, and these are not the real column names in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution it was that the declared variable name and column name were same so the ambiguity.
Basically what I have seen is that whenever new variable kr declare or input parameter is considered. That name should not match with any column names we are trying sect or insert into